Simple "AND Search in Mimecast for Outlook
We have Mimecast for Outlook installed and it's the only way we have of searching our inboxes and archive folders; it's not perfect but it's usually OK, except when I want to search for emails containing both of two words - the search always runs as "OR" rather than "AND".
For example, if I wanted to search my inbox for all emails containing the words "Stack" and "Exchange" I would expect to enter Stack AND Exchange or +Stack +Exchange or even Stack && Exchange but none of those work (in fact, using Stack AND Exchange returns any email containing Stack, or And or Exchange or any combination of them).
I've searched the Mimecast online documentation and it doesn't seem to mention anything about this sort of search in the client but goes into detail about setting up search tokens (which requires admin rights I don't have).
Does anyone know of a way to perform a simple "AND" search - am I, for example, just missing something obvious?
Thanks.

I'm afraid there is no article indicating how AND searches on Mimecast for Outlook .
